# Can I disable only "show last page" button in mat-paginator?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I know that I can hide both first and last page button at once with **showFirstLastButtons** property.

Is there a way to hide and disable only last page button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no build in way to display only the first navigation button. What you could do instead is hide the last button with css.

The last button has the class `mat-paginator-navigation-last`. You can use that to do things like `visibility: hidden` or `display: none` to hide it.